# Best approach to store images in mvc app

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm planning to develop web app. to store real estate information.

Tech.  details: MSSQL, NHIBERNATE ORM, C#, ASP.NET MVC3

Property will have some properties like
`Created, Updated, Id, Name, ... and IList<Photo> Photos.` 
So here will have one to many relations, one property can have many photos. 
On the other side on Photo entity have reference to `Property object` and `ImageData and ImageMimeType` to store photos in db.

This solution is recommended in apress book mvc3 pro to store images, but I'm wondering  what will happen when these database become huge because of images that are stored inside.  Any thought are helpful.

Which approach do you use? Db or file path on the server?
Any thoughts, links are helpful.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: storing image data in a server is rarely recommended.  It usually results in large, unwieldy backups that are difficult to maintain and store and performance problems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this [article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/13/sql-server-do-not-store-images-in-database-store-location-of-images-url/) ....

Storing URL is much easier to ADD, EDIT, DELETE, Database size also reduces, as oppose to store image in binary format.